# how to set small Icon when pushing message in nodejs

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm usnig fcm for notification in nodejs. So I made this And when I push message from nodejs to android, I got message well. When the app is running, I can get the small Icon image. But when the app is not running, I got the notification with no image. how can I get the push message with image when the app is in background? here is my nodejs code

```
     let pushMsg = req.body.pushMsg;
    let groupName = req.body.groupName;
    console.log(groupName)
    var condition = "'"+groupName+"' in topics"; //"'all' in topics || 'industry-tech' in topics";
    var message = {
      notification: {
        title: 'schedule updated',
        body: pushMsg,
        image:'./upload/haiilogo.png'

        },
      condition: condition
    };

    admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I added manifest to default icon like this

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/haiilogo" />
```